# Adding dynamical amount of numbers

Tags: prolog, logic, logic-programming

Take a given database, e.g.

```
input(80).
input(30).
input(25).
input(90).
```

Compute the amount of inputs above 50 times 100, constrained to only taking /1 input.
e.g.

```
%compute(?integer).
compute(I).
I = 200 %seeing as input(80) and input(90) matches the condition of being above 50
```

I have tried the following prolog code to mimick the compute function, unsuccessfully:

```
compute(I) :- input(G), G>50, I is I+100.
```

The I+100 does not work as I intend.

Comment: Your `compute` doesn't work because the logic says, *`compute(I)` is true if `G` is an input, `G > 50`, and `I is I + 100`. There's no initial value for `I`, and if there were, it succeeds once `G > 50` for the first time. You really want an aggregation of all the possible values, which can be done with `findall`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prolog is searching the matches one by one, and returning query result for EACH input, not for all of them. To collect all of the matching values, you can use `bagof`, `setof` or `findall` metapredicates.
Here is the code that is doing what you have defined:

```
input(80).
input(30).
input(25).
input(90).

compute(I) :- 
    findall(X, (input(X), X>50), L), % Find all X's that are 'input' and >50 into L
    length(L,Len),                  % Find the length of L and put into Len
    I is Len * 100.                 % I is Len times 100
```